# Convert Image to ASCII Art

Tags: python

I have used a tutorial to program this Image to ASCII Art converter, but it gives me an error. Here is the code:

```
import PIL.Image
from tkinter import filedialog

# Ascii characters
ASCII_CHARS = ["@", "#" ,"S" ,"%" ,"?" ,"*" ,"+" , ";", ":", "," "."]

def resize_image(image,new_width=100):
    width,height =image.size
    ratio = height / width / 1.65
    new_height = int(new_width*ratio)
    resized_image = image.resize((new_width,new_height))
    return(resized_image)

# convert each pixel to grayscale
def grayscaler(image):
    grayscale_image = image.convert("L")
    return(grayscale_image)

#convert pixels to a string of ASCII characters
def pixels_to_ascii(image):
    pixels = image.getdata()
    characters = "".join([ASCII_CHARS[pixel // 25]for pixel in pixels])
    return(characters)

def main(new_width=100):
    # Get image path
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select an image", filetypes=(("Image File", "*.png"),("all files", "*.*")))
    try:
        image = PIL.Image.open(path)
    except:
        print(path, "is not a valid pathname to an image")
    
    # convert image to ascii
    new_image_data = pixels_to_ascii(grayscaler(resize_image(image)))

    # format
    pixel_count = len(new_image_data)
    ascii_image = "\n".join(new_image_data[i:(i+new_width)] for i in range(0, pixel_count, new_width))

    # print result
    print(ascii_image)

    # save result to "ascii_image.txt"
    with open("ascii_image.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(ascii_image)

main()
```

It is suposed to be printing and saving the ascii art. Instead of that, it gives me this error ay line 34, and 22:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Forna\Documents\PYTHON\Image to Ascii\main.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Forna\Documents\PYTHON\Image to Ascii\main.py", line 34, in main
    new_image_data = pixels_to_ascii(grayscaler(resize_image(image)))
  File "c:\Users\Forna\Documents\PYTHON\Image to Ascii\main.py", line 22, in pixels_to_ascii
    characters = "".join([ASCII_CHARS[pixel // 25]for pixel in pixels])
  File "c:\Users\Forna\Documents\PYTHON\Image to Ascii\main.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    characters = "".join([ASCII_CHARS[pixel // 25]for pixel in pixels])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It would be very nice if someone could help me.

Comment: Given that `ASCII_CHARS` is onle 10 chars long, your code for some reason relies on `pixel` being less than 260.

Comment: But 10 chars is less than 260

Comment: …and?  This is the problematic code: `ASCII_CHARS[pixel // 25]`

Comment: how can I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in
`ASCII_CHARS = ["@", "#" ,"S" ,"%" ,"?" ,"*" ,"+" , ";", ":", "," "."]`
There wasn't a `,` after `","` my bad